# Setter dict like a property in object

Tags: python

I try to use a dict like a property in a object. This is a toy class.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._b = {}

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b['some_key'] = value
```

The `@property` work correctly, but the `setter` give this error:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I guess the problem is that the new object can not access the dict. I have to create a new class of `dict` that allows me to do that?

Comment: Works fine for me in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. `a.b = 3; assert a.b == {'some_key': 3}`.

Comment: Show code which raises error

Answer (score 1):

Your error is likely that somewhere you call the function `b` explicitly. e.g.

```
x = A();
x.b();
```

`@property` disallows normal calling of the function, and treats `b` completely as a normal instance variable, which is obviously not callable.